# CSV Export/Import with PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpexcel

Could you please guide me or provide me with some sample codes for performing CSV export and import using the PHPExcel library?

Excel export and import is fine but I need CSV export/import as well. I have other means of CSV export and import, but can it be done via PHPExcel also?

Comment: Note: [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) is the next version of PHPExcel. See [how to export/import CSV files with PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#csv-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score 78):

To import a CSV file into a PHPExcel object

```
$inputFileType = 'CSV';
$inputFileName = 'testFile.csv';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

To export a CSV file from a PHPExcel object

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$objWriter->save('testExportFile.csv');
```

**EDIT**

How to read through the rows and cells:

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo 'Row number: ' . $row->getRowIndex() . "\r\n";

    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        if (!is_null($cell)) {
            echo 'Cell: ' . $cell->getCoordinate() . ' - ' . $cell->getValue() . "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

How to write to a PHPExcel object:
You don't say where your data comes from: here's how to do it from a MySQL Query

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, age, date_of_birth, salary FROM employees WHERE firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'First Name')
                              ->setCellValue('B'.$row, 'Last Name')
                              ->setCellValue('C'.$row, 'Age')
                              ->setCellValue('D'.$row, 'Date of birth')
                              ->setCellValue('E'.$row, 'Salary');
$row++;
while ($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $rec['firstname'])
                                  ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $rec['lastname'])
                                  ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $rec['age'])
                                  ->setCellValue('D'.$row, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::stringToExcel($rec['date_of_birth']))
                                  ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $rec['salary']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('£#,##0.00');
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: thanks mark. but could you please let me have some more details on how to read line by line from the csv file or how to write to the csv file?

Comment: You can also use this syntax:
`$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);`

With `require_once '[your_libs]/PHPExcel/Writer/CSV.php';`

Comment: You shouldn't really need to require_once the CSV Writer: the autoloader should automatically include it when you do new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel)

Comment: awful documentation by the developer

Comment: @kratos - gee thanks.... so how would you document it? How can the documentation be improved? When will people get off negative criticism and start trying to be positive for a change?

Comment: OK, Mark, the answer is great, I'm using setDelimiter setEnclosure setLineEnding setInputEncoding, but how can I set also the escape character?

Comment: @Mark Baker Can you please help me how can I Insert that csv file data to database. I am able to save file to server but I am not able to save that data to database.

Comment: Great Work!! Superb answer! Thank you.! @MarkBaker

Comment: @MarkBaker, your answer solved my issue. +1 definitely.

Answer (score 5):

I been seeking the same thing. Excel CSV dosn't always use the quote separators and escapes the quotes using "" because the algorithm was probably made back the 80's or something. After looking at several .csv parsers in the comments section on PHP.NET, I seen ones that even used callbacks or eval'd code and they either didnt work like needed or simply didnt work at all. So, I wrote my own routines for this and they work in the most basic PHP configuration. The array keys can either be numeric or named as the fields given in the header row. Hope this helps.

```
    function SW_ImplodeCSV(array $rows, $headerrow=true, $mode='EXCEL', $fmt='2D_FIELDNAME_ARRAY')
    // SW_ImplodeCSV - returns 2D array as string of csv(MS Excel .CSV supported)
    // AUTHOR: tgearin2@gmail.com
    // RELEASED: 9/21/13 BETA
      { $r=1; $row=array(); $fields=array(); $csv="";
        $escapes=array('\r', '\n', '\t', '\\', '\"');  //two byte escape codes
        $escapes2=array("\r", "\n", "\t", "\\", "\""); //actual code

        if($mode=='EXCEL')// escape code = ""
         { $delim=','; $enclos='"'; $rowbr="\r\n"; }
        else //mode=STANDARD all fields enclosed
           { $delim=','; $enclos='"'; $rowbr="\r\n"; }

          $csv=""; $i=-1; $i2=0; $imax=count($rows);

          while( $i < $imax )
          {
            // get field names
            if($i == -1)
             { $row=$rows[0];
               if($fmt=='2D_FIELDNAME_ARRAY')
                { $i2=0; $i2max=count($row);
                  while( list($k, $v) = each($row) )
                   { $fields[$i2]=$k;
                     $i2++;
                   }
                }
               else //if($fmt='2D_NUMBERED_ARRAY')
                { $i2=0; $i2max=(count($rows[0]));
                  while($i2<$i2max)
                   { $fields[$i2]=$i2;
                     $i2++;
                   }
                }

               if($headerrow==true) { $row=$fields; }
               else                 { $i=0; $row=$rows[0];}
             }
            else
             { $row=$rows[$i];
             }

            $i2=0;  $i2max=count($row); 
            while($i2 < $i2max)// numeric loop (order really matters here)
            //while( list($k, $v) = each($row) )
             { if($i2 != 0) $csv=$csv.$delim;

               $v=$row[$fields[$i2]];

               if($mode=='EXCEL') //EXCEL 2quote escapes
                    { $newv = '"'.(str_replace('"', '""', $v)).'"'; }
               else  //STANDARD
                    { $newv = '"'.(str_replace($escapes2, $escapes, $v)).'"'; }
               $csv=$csv.$newv;
               $i2++;
             }

            $csv=$csv."\r\n";

            $i++;
          }

         return $csv;
       }

    function SW_ExplodeCSV($csv, $headerrow=true, $mode='EXCEL', $fmt='2D_FIELDNAME_ARRAY')
     { // SW_ExplodeCSV - parses CSV into 2D array(MS Excel .CSV supported)
       // AUTHOR: tgearin2@gmail.com
       // RELEASED: 9/21/13 BETA
       //SWMessage("SW_ExplodeCSV() - CALLED HERE -");
       $rows=array(); $row=array(); $fields=array();// rows = array of arrays

       //escape code = '\'
       $escapes=array('\r', '\n', '\t', '\\', '\"');  //two byte escape codes
       $escapes2=array("\r", "\n", "\t", "\\", "\""); //actual code

       if($mode=='EXCEL')
        {// escape code = ""
          $delim=','; $enclos='"'; $esc_enclos='""'; $rowbr="\r\n";
        }
       else //mode=STANDARD 
        {// all fields enclosed
          $delim=','; $enclos='"'; $rowbr="\r\n";
        }

       $indxf=0; $indxl=0; $encindxf=0; $encindxl=0; $enc=0; $enc1=0; $enc2=0; $brk1=0; $rowindxf=0; $rowindxl=0; $encflg=0;
       $rowcnt=0; $colcnt=0; $rowflg=0; $colflg=0; $cell="";
       $headerflg=0; $quotedflg=0;
       $i=0; $i2=0; $imax=strlen($csv);   

       while($indxf < $imax)
         {
           //find first *possible* cell delimiters
           $indxl=strpos($csv, $delim, $indxf);  if($indxl===false) { $indxl=$imax; }
           $encindxf=strpos($csv, $enclos, $indxf); if($encindxf===false) { $encindxf=$imax; }//first open quote
           $rowindxl=strpos($csv, $rowbr, $indxf); if($rowindxl===false) { $rowindxl=$imax; }

           if(($encindxf>$indxl)||($encindxf>$rowindxl))
            { $quoteflg=0; $encindxf=$imax; $encindxl=$imax;
              if($rowindxl<$indxl) { $indxl=$rowindxl; $rowflg=1; }
            }
           else 
            { //find cell enclosure area (and real cell delimiter)
              $quoteflg=1;
              $enc=$encindxf; 
              while($enc<$indxl) //$enc = next open quote
               {// loop till unquoted delim. is found
                 $enc=strpos($csv, $enclos, $enc+1); if($enc===false) { $enc=$imax; }//close quote
                 $encindxl=$enc; //last close quote
                 $indxl=strpos($csv, $delim, $enc+1); if($indxl===false)  { $indxl=$imax; }//last delim.
                 $enc=strpos($csv, $enclos, $enc+1); if($enc===false) { $enc=$imax; }//open quote
                 if(($indxl==$imax)||($enc==$imax)) break;
               }
              $rowindxl=strpos($csv, $rowbr, $enc+1); if($rowindxl===false) { $rowindxl=$imax; }
              if($rowindxl<$indxl) { $indxl=$rowindxl; $rowflg=1; }
            }

           if($quoteflg==0)
            { //no enclosured content - take as is
              $colflg=1;
              //get cell 
             // $cell=substr($csv, $indxf, ($indxl-$indxf)-1);
              $cell=substr($csv, $indxf, ($indxl-$indxf));
            }
           else// if($rowindxl > $encindxf)
            { // cell enclosed
              $colflg=1;

             //get cell - decode cell content
              $cell=substr($csv, $encindxf+1, ($encindxl-$encindxf)-1);

              if($mode=='EXCEL') //remove EXCEL 2quote escapes
                { $cell=str_replace($esc_enclos, $enclos, $cell);
                }
              else //remove STANDARD esc. sceme
                { $cell=str_replace($escapes, $escapes2, $cell);
                }
            }

           if($colflg)
            {// read cell into array
              if( ($fmt=='2D_FIELDNAME_ARRAY') && ($headerflg==1) )
               { $row[$fields[$colcnt]]=$cell; }
              else if(($fmt=='2D_NUMBERED_ARRAY')||($headerflg==0))
               { $row[$colcnt]=$cell; } //$rows[$rowcnt][$colcnt] = $cell;

              $colcnt++; $colflg=0; $cell="";
              $indxf=$indxl+1;//strlen($delim);
            }
           if($rowflg)
            {// read row into big array
              if(($headerrow) && ($headerflg==0))
                {  $fields=$row;
                   $row=array();
                   $headerflg=1;
                }
              else
                { $rows[$rowcnt]=$row;
                  $row=array();
                  $rowcnt++; 
                }
               $colcnt=0; $rowflg=0; $cell="";
               $rowindxf=$rowindxl+2;//strlen($rowbr);
               $indxf=$rowindxf;
            }

           $i++;
           //SWMessage("SW_ExplodeCSV() - colcnt = ".$colcnt."   rowcnt = ".$rowcnt."   indxf = ".$indxf."   indxl = ".$indxl."   rowindxf = ".$rowindxf);
           //if($i>20) break;
         }

       return $rows;
     }
```

...Now bob can do his spreadsheets

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Upload'])) {
     $fname = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];

     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv" || strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "xls" || strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "xlsx") {


         $filename = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "''09'")) !== FALSE)
         {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_upload(up_proj,up_loc,up_sys,up_dev,up_devtype,up_mnf,up_devtag,up_conn,up_readtag,up_ipaddr,up_warr,up_rem) VALUES('" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[11]). "','" .mysql_real_escape_string($data[12]). "')";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
         } //while

         fclose($handle);
         echo "Successfully Uploaded";
     } //if
     else
     {
         echo "Invalid File";
     }    
}//submit

?>
```

Comment: This does not use PHPExcel, which is what is asked for.