# PHP: parsing excel documents with formula's vs converting to CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have an excel document that I want to parse in PHP.  The way I see it I have 2 options.  1)Parse the excel with a library like PHPExcel. 2) Convert the document to CSV and then parse that file.

I feel like it would be easier to convert the document to CSV, but what worries me is a lot of the fields are computed from formulas.  Will I have a problem parsing out the calculated fields if I convert it to a CSV?

Comment: Just make sure when you convert it to CSV, you're saving the output instead of the formula.

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo Alright, how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: Use the [built in CSV export of Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmexport).

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo Can I automate that in PHP?  The user is going to upload the image and I want to parse it without having to manually do anything.

Comment: Ah I see. PHPExcel supports cleanly exporting data to CSV. [Check this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895819/csv-export-import-with-phpexcel)

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo Will that convert on the output instead of the formula?

Comment: Yeah, it uses the output instead of the formula.